# How to set a pointer to the end of string so that it ignores the last character?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memcpy

I recently started with programming and I dont know how I could set the pointer at the end of these strings and set it somehow that it ignores the last character and continues with the next line.
This code is supposed to separate the input in 8,4,4,4,4,4,diff,diff columns. All the lines of the input start with U. The code will ignore the first character ( meaning 'U') and separates the rest starting with the second character. The problem is now, when one line ENDS with 'U', it takes it as the first character of the following line, and it doesnt separate the following line correctly. I want to set it somehow that it ignores the 'U's if they are not the first character of the line.

Here are a few lines with this problem:

Input:

```
U6C862080032C00FD00000356F87C
U6C9ECB0002BC016C00000386F976í
U6CB77580024E01D900000396FA70U
U6CD0588001DD0247000003A6FB6A5
```

Output:

```
6C862080;032C;00FD;0000;0356;F87C;70
6C9ECB00;02BC;016C;0000;0386;F976;6E
6CB77580;024E;01D9;0000;0396;FA70;24D

U6CD058;8001;DD02;4700;0003;A6FB;E24
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX_LINES = 2000000;

char s[1000];
char s1[1000];
char *ps;
char *ps1;
long lines;
FILE *fptrIn, *fptrOut;



int hex_dec(char *s)
{
    long length=0, base =1, decimal=0;
     length = strlen(s);
    for(int i = length--; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
        {
            decimal += (s[i] - 48) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F')
        {
            decimal += (s[i] - 55) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f')
        {
            decimal += (s[i] - 87) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
    }
    return decimal;
}

void dec_hex(long out,char *s)
{
     int j = 0,remainder;
    
    while (out != 0)
    {
         remainder = out % 16;
        if (remainder < 10)
            s[j++] = 48 + remainder;
        else
            s[j++] = 55 + remainder;
        out = out / 16;
    }
}
void convertData(char *s, char *s2) {
    
    char ss[29];
    char *tail = ss+1;

    if ( *s !='U')
      return;
    s[29] = 0;

    if ( *tail =='U')
    {
        lines ++;
        return;
    }
    
    
    long out,diff1,diff2;

    char gp1[8 + 1] = {0};
    char gp2_1[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp2_2[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gpdiff1[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gpdiff2[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp3_1[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp3_2[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp4[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp5[4 + 1] = {0};
    char gp6[4 + 1] = {0};
    
    strncpy(gp1, s + 1, 8);
    strncpy(gp2_1, s + 9, 4);
    strncpy(gp2_2, s2 + 9, 4);
    strncpy(gp3_1, s + 13, 4);
    strncpy(gp3_2, s2 + 13, 4);
    strncpy(gp4, s + 17, 4);
    strncpy(gp5, s + 21, 4);
    strncpy(gp6, s + 25, 4);

   
    diff1=(hex_dec(gp2_1)-hex_dec(gp2_2))&0x0FFF;
    if (diff1 > 4096) 
     diff1 = 4096 - hex_dec(gp2_1)+hex_dec(gp2_2);
    dec_hex(diff1,gpdiff1);
    
    diff2=(hex_dec(gp3_1)-hex_dec(gp3_2))&0x0FFF;
    if (diff2 > 4096) 
     diff2 = 4096 -  hex_dec(gp3_1)+hex_dec(gp3_2);
    dec_hex(diff2,gpdiff2);

    
    fprintf(fptrOut, "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s\n", gp1, gp2_1, gp3_1, gp4, gp5, gp6,strrev(gpdiff1),strrev(gpdiff2));
}







int main() {

    

    FILE *f = fopen("testc.txt", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);  /* same as rewind(f); */

    char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
    fclose(f);



    fptrOut = fopen("testout.txt", "w");

    fprintf(fptrOut, "Position;Sens1;Sens2;Sens3;Check;Time;DiffSens1;Diffsens2\n");
    int charCounter = 0;  
    ps = string;  
    while (ps < string+fsize ) 

    {
        if(*ps+28!='U')
        ps = strchr(ps+1,'U');
       ps1 = strchr(ps+1,'U');
        memcpy(s,(void *)(ps),29);
        memcpy(s1,(void *)(ps1),29);
       
        lines++;

        printf("Line %d#:\n", lines);
        printf("%s\n", s);
        convertData(s,s1);
    
        if (lines == MAX_LINES) {
            break;
        }
        
    }

    
    fclose(fptrOut);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Test for `'\n'` rather than `'U'` to determine line end.

Comment: To begin with, if the input file is a text-file, then open it and read it as a text-file. If the records in it are line-based, then read it line by line. That will simplify your processing by quite a lot.

Comment: Unrelated note: You should not use such magic numbers: `s[j++] = 48 + remainder;` If you mean `'0'`, use `'0'`. Don't use numbers.

Comment: `for(int i = length--;` What is purpose of `--` here? You do not use `length` anymore in that function and it will not affect value that is assigned to `i`.

Comment: Instead of e.g. `if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')` use `if(isdigit(s[i])`. Please learn about [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the problem for what it is.
The problem is to 'sprinkle' semi-colons into the string that has been read from the source TXT file.
Because it is a TXT file, it should be opened with "t", not "b" (for "binary").

Here is a compiled array of strings representing lines read from a file.

Congratulations on your hex conversion functions.

I've not attempted the "diff" aspects of your problem. Perhaps you can work out another parameter to `prnFld()` that will `strncpy()` each of the appropriate 4 chars into another string buffer.

```
char *list[] = {
    "U6C862080032C00FD00000356F87C",
    "U6C9ECB0002BC016C00000386F976í",
    "U6CB77580024E01D900000396FA70U",
    "U6CD0588001DD0247000003A6FB6A5",
};

char *prnFld( char *cp, int size ) {
    printf( "%.*s;", size, sp );
    return cp + size;
}

void main( void ) {

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        char *cp = list[i];

        cp++; // skip the 'U'
        cp = prnFld( cp, 8 );
        cp = prnFld( cp, 4 );
        cp = prnFld( cp, 4 );
        cp = prnFld( cp, 4 );
        cp = prnFld( cp, 4 );
        cp = prnFld( cp, 4 );

        /* Calc those diffs and output them here */

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
6C862080;032C;00FD;0000;0356;F87C;
6C9ECB00;02BC;016C;0000;0386;F976;
6CB77580;024E;01D9;0000;0396;FA70;
6CD05880;01DD;0247;0000;03A6;FB6A;
```